# When i passing values from outside, it was taking default values only. how can i debug this issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

By default b and c values should be 0. when I pass some parameters it should be taken but when I passing parameters only default values are taking. why it is not taking parameters which i passing

The Code:

```
import sys

def add(a, b, c):
   d = int(a) + int(b) + int(c)
   print "add: " + str(d)

def main():
   a = sys.argv[1]
   b = sys.argv[2]
   c = sys.argv[3]
   ret = add(a, b=0, c=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like,

```
import sys

def add(a, b=0, c=0):
   d = int(a) + int(b) + int(c)
   print "add: " + str(d)

def main():
   a = sys.argv[1]
   b = sys.argv[2]
   c = sys.argv[3]
   ret = add(a, b=5, c=6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? These names are not defined.

Comment: x and y are the numbers whatever you want to pass. Updated the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get values from `sys.argv` , and default to zero if not set , you could try something like this :

```
a = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 0
b = sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else 0
c = sys.argv[3] if len(sys.argv) > 3 else 0
ret = add(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

The values b and c referenced in main are different to the ones in the inputs for add().

Consider this as a way to clarify which values are passed.

```
def main():
   x = sys.argv[1]
   y = sys.argv[2]
   z = sys.argv[3]
   ret = add(x, b=y, c=z)
```

You could set `b = sys.argv[2]` and then call `add(a, b=b, c)` to keep the same names.

Regarding how to set default values which are to be used if no values are specified, it is best practice to do put defaults in the function. Within `add` in your case.

```
import sys

def add(a, b=0, c=0): # default b and c to 0 but a is not set with default
   d = int(a) + int(b) + int(c)
   print "add: " + str(d)
   return d # return value otherwise you return None

def main():
   a = sys.argv[1]
   b = sys.argv[2]
   c = sys.argv[3]
   # store d from add() to ret variable.
   ret = add(a, b, c)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```